# How to create new file/script by Linux in OpenWrt

Tags: python, linux, command-line, openwrt

Hi there I have a router with OpenWrt and to enable a Startupscript, I first have to create the script.

I needt to create it in /etc/init.d/

The script is called swapon. So when I enter /etc/init.d/swapon I enter VI mode and type the script
Then I exit editing mode and type :w to save

Then it says 'error no such file or directory'

So how to create this script and let it save?

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

You need to be root to edit things in /etc/. Try the following:

1. Make sure [sudo](http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/secure.access#allow_temporary_privileged_access_using_sudo) is installed
2. Edit the file using `sudo vi /etc/init.d/swapon`
3. If it still complains, create the file first using `sudo touch /etc/init.d/swapon`
4. Finally, make sure the directory exists - if not, use `sudo mkdir /etc/init.d`